# I have problem updating a subdocument in an array of subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problems updating a subdocument in an array of subdocuments.

Here is my data structure in the users collection:

```
{
  favorites: [
    {
      id: new ObjectId("639707f36bf9468265d91810"),
      expiresAt: 1671361200000,
      reminder: false
    },
    {
      id: new ObjectId("637cc4c986b4fbec43579e1f"),
      expiresAt: 1672603200000,
      reminder: false
    }
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("637e8af40e43f40373686da2"),
  email: 'something@something.com',
  forename: 'something',
  surname: 'something',
  role: 'user',
  password: 'something',
  __v: 0
}
```

My Schema is:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  forename: String,
  surname: String,
  role: String,
  password: String,
  favorites: {
    id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Event" },
    expiresAt: Number,
    reminder: Boolean,
  },
});
```

I want to update the reminder field in a subdocument based on the subdocument’s id.

I’ve tried following approaches:

1.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.user, "favorites.id":  { $eq: BSON.ObjectId(req.body.id) } },
      { $set: { "favorites.$.reminder": true } },
    ).setOptions({ sanitizeFilter: true });
```

Here nothing happens. It finds the document but does not update it.

2.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.user },
      { $set: { "favorites.$[elem].reminder": true } },
      {
        arrayFilters: [{ "elem.id": { $eq: BSON.ObjectId(req.body.id) } }],
        returnNewDocument: true,
      }
    ).setOptions({ sanitizeFilter: true });
```

Here it returns an error: “Error: Could not find path “favorites.0.id” in schema”

I cannot find where is my mistake? Any help is much appreciated!

P.S.

Mongo version is 5.0.14

Comment: Okay, now I found where was the error ... in my Schema.

The favorites in my Schema are object but should be array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use updateMany instead.

```
User.updateMany(
  {
    _id: userId,
    "favorites.id": eventId
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "favorites.$.reminder": true
    }
  },
  function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    } else {
      // Handle success
    }
  }
);
```

I think you can adapt the query to your calling method findOneAndUpdate. But it's enough to you.

Comment: I found where my mistake was ... in my Schema. The favorites in my Schema are an object but should be an array.